# Prevent ngClass in angular 8 When Form load

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I have input field like this

mycomponet.html

```
 <input #first_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'red-border-class': first_name.errors}" type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="first_name" [(ngModel)]="student.first_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" required>
```

And mystyle.css like

```
.red-border-class { border: 1px solid red; }
```

The problem is the ngClass its gets applyed at first when i load a page and i what it to apply when user touch the input field and left it without enter anything.. How can i solve this problem?.

Comment: You can use the "edit" command to modify the question. Can we see your attempt with `ngClass`?

Answer (score 1):

see if your `first_name.errors` is true. As`ngClass` adds the class Name only when the condition is `true`

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class':true}"
[ngClass]="{'my-class':false}"
```

> Here in the first case only the class `my-class` will be applied but not in the second case as the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[class.red-border-class]="first_name.invalid && first_name.touched"
```

Comment: If this is to be helpful, explain what `touched` does in the answer, or at least point to documentation.

Comment: Hi, as I remember correctly - control marks at `touched` when it lost focus for the first time. So, that's why I've used it here - we check if input field invalid && input field lost focus (at least once) - show the error

Comment: @InnoMgubhe, Not at all! Please, mark this answer as a solution. Thanks in advance)

Comment: The response to my comment should be in the body of the answer. It is a key part of the answer. Please consider editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[ngClass]="{'red-border-class': first_name.errors && first_name.dirty}"
```

Refer the below link to have better understanding of reactive forms:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Hope this works

Comment: If this is to be helpful, explain what `dirty` does in the answer, or at least point to documentation.

Comment: You may not want your application to display errors before the user has a chance to edit the form. The checks for dirty and touched prevent errors from showing until the user does one of two things: changes the value, turning the control dirty; or blurs the form control element, setting the control to touched. Refer: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Hope this will help you better

Comment: The response to my comment should be in the body of the answer. It is a key part of the answer. PS: I know, others might not